# Explain usage of “have had been”

Tags: tense, present-perfect, past-perfect

I am very much confused with the usage of Have-Had-Has.
I know "have" is used in Present perfect whereas "had" is used in past perfect.
Then what about **the usage of "have had" combination** in a sentence?

Where do I have to use them?

How I know whether my usage is correct or not?

Comment: @MaulikV I think OP has a more fundamental confusion, between auxiliary and lexical *HAVE*, which needs to be addressed. I am for keeping the question open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what is confusing you is that *HAVE* may be used in two different roles:

- as a lexical (‘main’) verb, in a variety of senses:

  > I **have** two cats. ... *Here* have *means* ‘possess’.
  >   I **have** a system for feeding my cats. ... *Here* have *means* ‘maintain’.
  >   I **have** Bob feed my cats when I am away. ... *Here* have *means* ‘cause’ *somebody* ‘to’ *do something*.

  These are only a sample; there are many other senses for lexical *HAVE*.
- as an auxiliary (‘helping’) verb, in perfect constructions:

  > I **have fed** my cats. ... *Here* have *combines with the past participle of the lexical verb* feed *to form a present perfect construction*.

  The perfect may also appear in other tenses, and in tenseless constructions, and in combination with progressive and passive constructions.

  > I **had fed** my cats. ... *past perfect*
  >   I **will have fed** my cats. ... *future perfect*
  >   My cats **have been fed**.  ... *present perfect passive*
  >   I **have been feeding** my cats. ... *present perfect progressive*
  >   My cats **have been being fed**.  ... *present perfect progressive passive*
  >   I want **to have fed** my cats by 5 o’clock. ...  *infinitive perfect*
  >   **Having fed my cats**, I will make my own dinner. ... *participial perfect*

  ... and so forth. There is a *lot* more about perfect constructions at [*What is the perfect, and how should I use it?*](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/13255/32).

The **have had** construction you ask about employs *HAVE* in **both** roles, auxiliary and lexical, in the same sentence.

> I **have had** many cats over the last fifty years.
>   I **have had** Bob feed my cats in the past, but now Lucy feeds them.

In these two sentences, the first *HAVE* form, *have*, is an auxiliary, but the second, *had*, is lexical *HAVE*, cast as a past participle, just like *fed* in the previous examples.

Answer (score 4):

**has** and **have**

*has* and *have*, when used **alone**, are both used to describe a recurrent state of possession, or participation:

- I have a conversation with my mother every morning.
- She has a conversation with her mother every morning.
- I have dark hair.
- She has dark hair.
- I have black shoes.
- She has black shoes.

When deciding whether to use *has* or *have*:

- has is used only with a *third-* person subject: that is, *you*, *he*, *she*, *it*,  or any named subject (John, Australia, the Queen)
- have is used only with a *first-* or *second-* person subject: that is, *I* or *you*.

---

**have/has had**

**have had** and **has had** are used, as noted by [Veronica Diamond](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/6674/veronica-diamond) in [her answer (which has now been deleted)](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/24214/1407), to describe something that has happened in the past.

The technical term for this is [the present perfect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Present_perfect#English). In **perfect** is a technical term meaning *completed*, and so it roughly means: something that has been completed - now.

As mentioned by [StoneyB](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/32/stoneyb), in this form, *have* is a *auxiliary* ("helping") verb, which temporally "sets" the time for the main verb, which can be any verb, not just "have".

This may take the form of a circumstance of time that links it to the present:

- They have had three exams in the last week
- She has had three exams in the last week

However, this circumstance is *not* obligatory:

- I have had dinner at that restaurant a dozen times.
- She has had dinner at that restaurant a dozen times.

In the examples above, I (or she) could have had dinner at the restaurant a dozen times *fifty years ago*, or *in the last year*. But it's not necessary to provide a timespan.